# Get data in Async Task in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to receive data inside `AsyncTask` class, a `list` sent as parameter from other  class. I am unable to receive list in he `Async` class. Thanks in advance.

```
 classforAsync classforAsyncO = new classforAsync();
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(myList);
                System.out.println("Going");
                classforAsync(myList).execute();
            }
        });
```

**Async Class**

```
public class classforAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
 private String[] list;
 String str1,str2;


public classforAsync (String[] list ) {
    this.list = list;
    this.str1 = list[0];
    this.str2 = list[1];
}
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        System.out.println("IN ");
        System.out.println(str1);
        System.out.println(str2);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You must have a constructor in place to pass in your list. Update the `type` accordingly.

```
public class classforAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

private List<String> list;

public classforAsync(List<String> list) { 
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    System.out.println("IN ");
    String str1 = list.get(0);
    String str2 = list.get(1);
    System.out.println(str1);
    System.out.println(str2);
    return null;
  }
}
```

And you pass in the list like this

> new classforAsync(myList).execute();

Comment: this is prining `System.out.println("IN ");` `str1` and `str2` not.

Comment: You are calling `classforAsync.execute(myList);` and it's wrong. It should be `new classforAsync(myList).execute();`. See the difference?

Comment: still not rinting

Comment: Still not printing

Comment: See my constructor. I think i a doing god. But not printing the `str1` and `str2`

Comment: Pls debug using `Arrays.toString ()` and see if your list values get printed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
public class classforAsync extends AsyncTask<List<?>, Void, Void> {

        private List<String> list;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List... params) {
            if (params[0] != null) {
                list = params[0];
                //Rest of the code goes here
                ...
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```